# Closed convex hull of a sequence of distributions

Tags: pr.probability, differential-equations

I encounter the following problem when trying to apply the theory of fractional derivatives. On the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, for an $\alpha>1$, define a distribution $p_{\alpha}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{\alpha}(n)$ is proportional to $1/n^{\alpha}$. For $m\geq 1$, I thus obtain a sequence of distributions on $\mathbb{N}$: $(p_{m\alpha})_{m\geq 1}$. The question is what is the closed convex hull of this sequence? Namely, what kind of distributions can we obtain by taking mixtures and limits of this sequence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what terms do you want this closed convex hull to be described?

Comment: I do not have a clue about what the answer should be. I was initially considering these $p_{m\alpha}$ as functions, and if I take the closure of the algebra generated by these functions then I can apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. However, for an application in mind, it will be more appropriate to just take the closure of convex combinations of these distributions, which leads to this question.

Comment: Are you interested in the closed convex hull over $m \in \mathbb{N}$ or the closed convex hull of $(p_{a})_{a \geq \alpha}$?

Comment: Primarily, I am interested in the closed convex hull over $m\in \mathbb{N}$ for a fixed $\alpha$. If this is impossible, a result involving countably many (irrational) $a>\alpha$ is also fine.